# Bubble sort on a text file using the file itself as a container

Tags: c#, file, sorting, streamreader

I am trying to write a bubble sort on a large text file that has 1 column of numbers that are all between 1 and 99.  I want to sort it without bringing the contents or the data in memory  at the same time. I used a loop of 20 passes to get the logic down before I do this on the whole file. I am using streamreader and streamwriter to receive and send the numbers back and forth so only 2 numbers are processed at any one time. the numbers in the text file are coded int32.I converted them in the writing process. I have been unable to populate the "sorted" file with the data.  Here is my code:

```
 static void BubbleSort()
    { 
        int bubbleOut, bubbleIn; 
        StreamReader readToSort = new StreamReader(@"C:Random # File.txt");
        StreamWriter writeSorted = new StreamWriter(@"C:Sorted_File.txt");
        bubbleIn = readToSort.Read();
        bubbleOut = readToSort.Read();

        for (bubbleIn = 1; bubbleIn <= 20; bubbleIn++)
        {
            for (bubbleOut = bubbleIn; bubbleIn < bubbleOut; bubbleOut++ )
            {
                if (bubbleOut > bubbleIn)
                {
                    int temp = bubbleIn;
                    bubbleIn = bubbleOut;
                    bubbleOut = temp;
                    writeSorted.WriteLine(bubbleIn);
                    writeSorted.WriteLine(bubbleOut);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The variable used for loop counter is same as the first number to compare, is that what you want to do? And for all those passes you are just swapping the same two values about.

Comment: you have 99 numbers but the sort ain't done

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for large data sets you better use MergeSort because it is much faster (`O(n log n)`) than BubbleSort (`O(n * n)`).

Besides that, you are only reading the first two characters of the inputstream and after reading the data, you override the value in the for-loop.

I think you first have to copy the entire content of in input file, to the output file. Then you need a way to swap 2 characters in the output stream. After that, you can run the bubblesort algorithm on the inputfile and apply the swap on the output file.

Your for-loop should look something like:

```
// TODO: Copy input to output

for (int sortedElement = 0; sortedElement < StreamLength; sortedElement++)
{
   // You don't have to loop till the end of the stream. Last
   // character is sorted on each iteration.
   for (int index = 0; index < StreamLength - sortedElements - 1; index++)
   {
       // read character from input stream at position 'index' as leftValue
       // read character from input stream at position 'index+1' as rightValue

       if (rightValue < leftValue)
       {
          // Perform swap values in outputfile
       }
   }
}
```

That should be it.

Comment: if the 'values are all between 1 and 99' surely there are even faster sort approaches for large files, just remember the start and end positions of your 99 blocks of 1's 2's 3's... etc

Comment: I think you can do it in 2 passes. O(n)?

Comment: I have no idea of the Big O notation when you are sending and receiving data with streamreader.  most likely O(N^2).